# How to get mouse events to work properly with multiple ImGui frames?

Tags: c++, glfw, imgui

I have an ImGui widget with code similar to this:

```
ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
ImGui::NewFrame();
ImGui::Begin("Window 1");
ImGui::Button("Hello 1");
ImGui::End();
ImGui::Render();
ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());
```

This runs fine.

If I add another frame, something like this:

```
ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
ImGui::NewFrame();
ImGui::Begin("Window 1");
ImGui::Button("Hello 1");
ImGui::End();
ImGui::Render();
ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
ImGui::NewFrame();
ImGui::Begin("Window 2");
ImGui::Button("Hello 2");
ImGui::End();
ImGui::Render();
ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());
```

It renders fine but any mouse click cause an *infinite recursion* when `glfwPollEvents()` is called (the recursion is in `ImGui_ImplGlfw_MouseButtonCallback(...)`).

*Note: I know I can perform several Begin(...) ... End(...) sequences without creating a new frame between them but I want the widgets to be **independent of each other**.*

This is the call stack btw:

```
.
.
.
ImGui_ImplGlfw_MouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int) imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:94
ImGui_ImplGlfw_MouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int) imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:94
ImGui_ImplGlfw_MouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int) imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:94
ImGui_ImplGlfw_MouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int) imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:94
ImGui_ImplGlfw_MouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int) imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:94
ImGui_ImplGlfw_MouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int) imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:94
_glfwInputMouseClick(_GLFWwindow *, int, int, int) input.c:350
windowProc(HWND__ *, unsigned int, unsigned long long, long long) win32_window.c:804
<unknown> 0x00007ffce6e4e858
<unknown> 0x00007ffce6e4e4ee
<unknown> 0x00007ffcb74702a0
<unknown> 0x00007ffce6e4e858
<unknown> 0x00007ffce6e4e299
_glfwPlatformPollEvents() win32_window.c:1977
glfwPollEvents() window.c:1092
Widget::NewFrame() Widget.cpp:20
Widget::Draw(const Eigen::Matrix<…> &, const Eigen::Matrix<…> &, const Eigen::Matrix<…> &, int, unsigned int) Widget.cpp:28
Movable::Draw(const Eigen::Matrix<…> &, const Eigen::Matrix<…> &, const Eigen::Matrix<…> &, int, unsigned int) Movable.cpp:160
Scene::Draw(int, const std::shared_ptr<…> &, unsigned int) Scene.cpp:30
```

Comment: *"want the widgets to be independent of each other"* What does that mean? ImGui might get fussy with this, because not drawing a widget for a frame might reset some of its state.

Comment: Creating several ImGui contexts might work better for this, though I still don't see the point.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you need two separate ImGui::Context but there is no need to use the docking branch, it works with the current official releases (1.90.x), here is how:

```
// declare two contexts

ImGuiContext* main_context;
ImGuiContext* secondary_context;

// mouse callbacks to send mouse inputs to the secondary context

void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
{
    ImGui::SetCurrentContext(secondary_context);

    ImGui_ImplGlfw_MouseButtonCallback(window, button, action, mods);

    ImGui::SetCurrentContext(g);
}

void set_cursor_pos_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double x, double y)
{
    ImGui::SetCurrentContext(secondary_context);

    ImGui_ImplGlfw_CursorPosCallback(window, x, y);

    ImGui::SetCurrentContext(main_context);
}

// main, only interesting code is left

int main(void)
{
    // init, configure GLFW and create the window
    // (...)
    
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouse_button_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, set_cursor_pos_callback);

    // create both contexts

    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    main_context = ImGui::CreateContext();
    // configure ImGui::GetIO() as usual
    // (...)
    
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL(window, true); // install_callback=true (IMPORTANT!)
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init();

    secondary_context = ImGui::CreateContext();
    {
        ImGui::SetCurrentContext(secondary_context);
    
        // configure ImGui::GetIO() as usual
        // (...)

        ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL(window, false); // install_callback=false (IMPORTANT!)
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init();

        ImGui::SetCurrentContext(main_context);
    }
    
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    
        // Render the main_context as usual
        // (...)
        
        {
            ImGui::SetCurrentContext(secondary_context);
        
            // Render the secondary_context as usual
            // (...)            
        
            ImGui::SetCurrentContext(main_context);
        }
    
        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();   
    }
    
    // destroy everything
    // (...)
    
    return 0;   
}
```

This is for mouse inputs, for keyboard inputs it should be the same method...

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create two different ImGui contexts (call `ImGui::CreateContext()` two times), and also initialize the backend two times for those contexts.

You will need to handle the `WndProc` and `ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData` for two separate contexts.

But ImGui doesn't recommend to do this, you might want to look at how the docking branch handles multiple viewports/windows [here](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/docking/backends/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp)

Or if your problem is simply window name collision (two ImGui window that have the same name), just add `##` after the name, for example: `"Window 1#win_1"` will be rendered as `Window 1`